# Extra period in section labels after redefinition of \theparagraph

Tags: numbering, paragraphs

I want the paragraphs in my document numerated with lowercase letters, followed by a period. So I added the line `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}}`  to my document which created the numbering I wanted. A side effect of this was however that periods also appeared after the Chapter/Section/Float numbers in their label (but not their reference!).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\label{sec:foo}
\ref{sec:foo}
\paragraph{Bar}\label{sec:bar}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

I noticed that this extra period is not added if I redefine `\theparagraph` with `\arabic`. Also, it appears only after the second compilation of the document.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of them are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: That period has nothing to do with `\theparagraph`, it is specified by who `\paragraph` is typeset.

Comment: @daleif It is merely my observation that this period is a direct consequence of the `\renewcommand` and `\setcounter` commands in my MWE. Unfortunately I know little about the inner workings. Could you maybe elaborate on your comment?

Comment: Delete your `\renewcommand...` and section etc., numbers are still followed by a period. This is the default for the class you are using. I have no idea how to remove the periods you object to.

Comment: @PeterWilson that is not true. If I delete the `\renewcommand...`, the trailing periods do not appear. Although indeed the described behaviour appears only with the `scr...` KOMA-classes.

Comment: It is true! In your MWE you use the `scrartcl` class and what i described occurs. Don't expect anyone to guess what you have actually done. If you are not prepared to show your problem code then don't accuse someone of lying. --- GOM

Comment: @PeterWilson KOMA Script's automatic to decide whether or not to place a period after the numbers relies on the `.aux` file. If the MWE is run as is at least twice with LaTeX, the numbers end in periods. If we uncomment the `\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}}`, the next LaTeX run will still show a period (but no alphabetic counters). Only subsequent LaTeX runs drop the period again. I believe this is just a confusion about the number of compile runs to see the effects and there was no intention to accuse anyone of lying here.

Comment: @moewe I don't use any of the KOMA classes. It seems very strange to me that the appearance of division titles depends on the number of compilations. Thank you for information.

Comment: Following the comment by @moewe I apologise for my earlier comment. I had no idea that the appearance of the division numbers in KOMA classes depended on the number of compilations; I only compiled for MWE once after deleting the `\renewcommand...`, and got the result I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a KOMA Script feature to add a period after (all sectioning) numbers as soon as there is a non-Arabic number at some level. To quote the [documentation (pp. 99-100 in 2021-06-25)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)

> According to DUDEN, if only Arabic numerals are used to number section headings, the German practice is to have no point at the end (see [DUD96, R3]). On the other hand, if Roman numerals or letters appear in the numbering, then a point should appear at the end of the numbering (see [DUD96, R4]). KOMA-Script has a mechanism that tries to automate this somewhat complex rule. The result is that normally after the sectioning commands `\part` and `\appendix` the numbering switches to using a final point. This information is saved in the `.aux` file and takes effect on the next LaTeX run.
>
> Sometimes the mechanism for placing or omitting the final point may fail. Sometimes other languages have different rules. Therefore you can force the use of the final point with the option `numbers=endperiod` or to prohibit it with `numbers=noendperiod`.
>
> Note that this mechanism only takes effect on the next LaTeX run. Therefore, before you try to use these options to force the correct numbering format, you should always perform another LaTeX run without modifying the document.

If you want to stick to the Duden rules, you have to do nothing.

If you want to get rid of the period, use `numbers=noendperiod`.

If you want to retain the period for the paragraph heading, you can additionally redefine `\paragraphformat` and replace `\autodot` with `.` to force a period.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noendperiod]{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}}
\renewcommand*{\paragraphformat}{\theparagraph.\enskip}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\label{sec:foo}
\ref{sec:foo}
\paragraph{Bar}\label{sec:bar}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Foo 1 a. Bar]

Answer (score 3):

How about using `article` instead of `scrartcl`?

[image]

```
%\documentclass{scrartcl}
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\alph{paragraph}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}\label{sec:foo}
\ref{sec:foo}
\paragraph{Bar}\label{sec:bar}
\paragraph{Barr}\label{sec:barr}

Paragraph~\ref{sec:bar} gives the proof.
Paragraph~\ref{sec:barr} gives an example.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Firstly, I'm a fan of the inline style of Paragraph headings. Secondly, unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the issue. This additional period seems to be a consequence of the `\alph`. It doesn't appear if I redefine using `\arabic` (or `\fnsymbol`)

Comment: @NielsKarschin, How about using `article` as shown in my updated answer?

Comment: That's not an option. I do use scrartcl over article (or scrbook over book, for that matter) for a variety of reasons. I cannot switch to a whole different document class for my PhD thesis for every small issue that appears along the way ;)